# Call function in master page from content page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a function in Master Page.
I want to call this function from content page.
My content page has been created from a nested master page and that function is into main master page. and my master pages are into a folder named "masters".
How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast [`Page.Master`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.master%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the actual type of your master. Then you are able to call that method:

```
var master = this.Master as MyMaster;
if(master != null)
  master.MethodName();
```

If your page is in a `MasterPage` that has another `MasterPage` as mentioned:

```
var mainMaster = master.Master as MyMainMaster;
if(mainMaster != null)
   mainMaster.MethodName();
```

Comment: @MajidBasirati: the master thas also a `Master`-property. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make your master page method `public` and use like this

```
((Site1)this.Master).Page_Load(sender, e);
```

Where `Site1` is your master page class.